# WWF Terrestrial Major Habitat Types

Tags: shapefile, biology

I need the shapefile of the map attached (or very very similar) - but I can't find. I attached it here.
Somewhere I found a picture where it is named "Terrestrial Major Habitat Types".

[image]

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Check this database, maybe it works for you: http://www.fao.org/land-water/land/land-governance/land-resources-planning-toolbox/category/details/en/c/1036295/

Answer (score 1):

No idea on the source of the map so, can only help so much. I am only answering here because I can clarify a spatial-attribute aspect of the data and aim you towards the correct dataset. The MHT's (Major Habitat Types) are an attribute in the Terrestrial Ecoregions dataset.

The original WWF Ecoregions report is available [here](https://www.worldwildlife.org/publications/terrestrial-ecoregions-of-the-world), which details the ecoregions and MHT's. However, I would recommend using [TNC's modification](https://geospatial.tnc.org/datasets/b1636d640ede4d6ca8f5e369f2dc368b), as it is the de facto standard for this data.